# Could Mathematica solve a differential equation asymptotically?

Tags: differential-equations, programming

Is there any possibility that Mathematica could give asymptotic behavior(s) of a differential equation as it independent variable tends to a certain value?

Because I didn't know how to **decompose** this hard problem, I just tried the naive code to find a trial solution to the 3rd-order nonlinear ODE:

$$H^2(H_{\eta\eta\eta}-\eta^{-2}H_\eta+\eta^{-1}H_{\eta\eta})-\frac{\eta}{10}=0,$$

which is subject to the boundary conditions: $H(0)=1$ and $H_{\eta\eta}(0)=-c$ with $c$ being a constant. If one wants to seek a solution $H(\eta)$ that is an even function in $\eta$.

```
DSolve[{H[\[Eta]]^2*(H'''[\[Eta]] - \[Eta]^-2 H'[\[Eta]] + 
   1/\[Eta] H''[\[Eta]]) - \[Eta]/10 == 0, H[0] == 1, 
   H''[0] == -c, H[\[Eta]] == H[-\[Eta]]}, H[\[Eta]], \[Eta]]
```

Mathematica complains that:

> DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {...} should literally match the independent variables.

Obviously, the error results from the *even function* condition, `H[\[Eta]] == H[-\[Eta]]`. If I comment this condition, the code just repeats itself without any solution. Another minor question is:

**How to impose an even or odd function requirement in `DSolve`?**

**Motivation:**
The reason why I arise this problem is that the asymptotic behavior of $H(\eta)$ has been shown (I guess by perturbation method which is powerful math tool) as follows. That can be used to check the desired code/method with MMA. I really want to consult superiors of MMA here for some suggestion about how to solve an exactly unsolvable differential equation with the asymptotic method. Thank you in advance!

$H \sim 1-\frac{1}{2}c\eta^2 \quad \text{as} \quad  \eta \to 0$

$H(\eta)=\tilde{h}F\left(\eta_0-\eta \right)$ near $\eta_0$, where
$H(\eta)$ reaches its minmum value for a given constant $c$, denoted by $\tilde{h}=H(\eta_0)$, $F(x)\sim x^2$ as $x\ll0$ and $F(x)\sim x(\log x)^{1/3}$ for large $x\gg0$.

Comment: If `H[η]` is well behaved near `η == 0`, then the symmetry requirement can be given by `H'[0] == 0`.  This being the case, it is straightforward to obtain a power series solution of the ODE near `η == 0`.  However, if you want an approximate solution at a value `η0` outside the radius of convergence of the power series at `η == 0`, then I see no way even in principle to apply the `η == 0` boundary conditions to the approximate solution at that `η0`.

Comment: Incidentally, -(3/(4 5^(1/3))) η^(4/3) satisfies the ODE identically but not the boundary condition `H[0] == 1`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thanks. For comment1: At $\eta=\eta_0$, could we impose these boundary conditions for the ODE:  $H_\eta(\eta_0)=0$, $\tilde{h}=H(\eta_0)$ and $H_{\eta\eta}(\eta_0)>0$, since it reaches its min $\tilde{h}$ at $\eta_0$?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thanks. For comment2: for your trial solution the boundary condition at $\eta=0$ is $H(0)=0$?

Comment: With respect to your two responses, (1) You can, in principle, impose the boundary conditions at `η0`, but how do you know what value `η0` has?  (2) Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to roll one's own asymptotic solver with the help of `Series`. As a demonstration, here we show how to obtain an asymptotic power series solution around zero.

The equations in OP, except the even function condition `H[η] == H[-η]` (which will turned out to be redundant for this particular problem), can be rearranged to (omit the `== 0` parts):

```
eqs = {
       H[η]^2*(H'''[η]-η^-2 H'[η]+1/η H''[η])-η/10,
       H[0] - 1,
       H''[0] + c
      };
```

If we assume the existence of power expansion about $x=0$:

$$H(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty h_k x^k$$

then a series representation of $H$ and its derivatives can be straightforwardly defined through following rules:

```
seriesRules = RightComposition[
    ReplaceAll[{
          H[x_] :>
                (Inactive[Series][H[η], {η, 0, max}] // Inactive[ReplaceAll][η -> x]),
          Derivative[s_Integer?Positive][H][x_] :>
                (Inactive[Series][Derivative[s][H][η], {η, 0, max}] // Inactive[ReplaceAll][η -> x])
        }],
    (* the odd/even function constraint can be described as following rule *)
    (* Inactive[ReplaceAll][{
          (* odd: *)(* H[0] :> 0,Derivative[s_Integer?EvenQ][H][0] :> 0 *)
          (* even: *)Derivative[s_Integer?OddQ][H][0] :> 0
        }], *)
    Inactive[ReplaceAll][{H[0] :> h[0], Derivative[s_Integer][H][0] :> h[s]}]
];
```

Applying it on `eqs` gives us its series version:

```
series = eqs // seriesRules;
```

For a given series order `max`, `series` can be `Activate`d to become algebra equations `serieseqs` about $h_0,h_1,...$:

```
asymptoticOrder = 10;
serieseqs = series //
               ReplaceAll[max -> asymptoticOrder] // Activate //
               Map[
                   If[Head[#] === SeriesData, #[[3]], #] &
                  ] //
               Flatten // Thread[# == 0] & // DeleteCases[True];
```

Luckily the equations we got here are all nice and easy to solve:

```
seriessol = Inactive[Solve][serieseqs, 
                            Union[Cases[serieseqs, _h, ∞]][[;; UpTo[Length@serieseqs]]]
                ] // Activate;
seriessol // Apply[List, #, {2}] & // Map[Grid[#, Frame -> All] &] // Row
```

[image: series coefficient solution]

Thus the corresponding approximate solution for $H$

```
H[η] // seriesRules //
        ReplaceAll[max -> asymptoticOrder] // Activate //
        ReplaceAll[seriessol]
```

[image: finite series solution for H]

(But do be aware this is only a formal series solution. The convergence is yet to prove.)

Comment: What is "UpTo" ? I get an error message: "1;;UpTo[13] is not a valid Span specification"

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec It's a handy function [introduced in version 10.3](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html). Should be easy to replace with something involving `Min`.

Comment: @Silvia Should we end up your final equation with $O(\eta^{12})$?

Comment: @W.Robin The calculation rules on `SeriesData` are built-in. They decided the exponent of $O(\eta^{11})$. In this case, there maybe the coefficient for the $\eta^{11}$ term stored at position `{3,12}` of `SeriesData[...]`, but it's the penultimate argument of it decides to which term to show in a StandardForm / TraditionalForm.

Answer (score 12):

Mathematica 11.3? Will have `AsymptoticDSolve` and support for these

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And WKB also

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It will also finally have series solution for `DSolve`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See Asymptotic Expansions at http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&p=3&v=2091

Comment: thanks for the information. I only have access to v9 and v10. Is there any workaround for this `AsymptoticDSolve` on the lower version?

Comment: @W.Robin I do not know of any Mathematica package which does this. You could wait for next version of M, and upgrade then.

Comment: @W.Robin Just to clarify: Mathematica 11.3 is not released yet.

Comment: @QuantumDot, thanks for the information. So I'd like to find a method to achieve this aim with a lower version :)

Comment: It did come out in 12? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html?q=AsymptoticDSolveValue

Answer (score 3):

It's not a answer of Yours question,only a info if `Mathematica 11.3` can solve or not.

Using `Mathematica 11.3`,it seems `can't` find solution.

[image]